# Diferença entre os tipos de botoes

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, button

Qual a diferença entre os seguintes componentes ?

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<asp:button ID="cmdAvancar" runat="server" >Click Me!</asp:button>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Digo por exemplo em propriedades, questão de eventos, manipulação, efeitos ao clicar.

Por exemplo se eu preciso utilizar o evento onsubmit do Javascript todos os 3 vão funcionar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `<input type="button" />` é o [tipo DOM primitivo da interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button). Em HTML5 ele foi substituído pelo elemento [`HTMLButtonElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement).
- `<button></button>`, ou `HTMLButtonElement`, é a versão HTML5. Pode ser do tipo `button`, `reset` ou `submit`.
- `<input type="submit" />` (e seu irmão `reset`) são derivações do elemento `button`. Certos comportamentos são associados por padrão:

  - `<input type="submit" />` envia o formulário sob cujo contexto o elemento existe;
  - `<input type="reset" />` retorna os os campos presentes para seus valores originais.
- `<asp:button>` não é um elemento HTML. É uma abstração da plataforma ASP.NET para permitir integração entre os ambientes *client-* e *server-side*. O renderer gera um elemento `<input type="button" />`, porém quando este é clicado um evento javascript é interceptado e uma chamada é submetida pra a aplicação, que resulta na invocação do evento *server-side* vinculado.

Comment: certo, mas e no caso do `onsubmit` sendo um evento `JS` ele funciona nos 3 componentes?

Comment: De acordo com a documentação (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit), sim - contanto que você não chame a função do formulário diretamente (`form.submit();`);

Answer (score 4):

O Button(`asp:button`) será renderizado no HTML como `<input type="submit">` ou como `<button>`. Isso vai depender as propriedades definidas.

---

Isto:

```
<asp:button ID="cmdAvancar" runat="server" >Click Me!</asp:button>
```

Será renderizado assim:

```
<input name="cmdAvancar" type="submit" value="Click Me" />
```

---

Isto

```
<asp:button ID="cmdAvancar" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior=false >Click Me!</asp:button>
```

Será renderizado assim:

```
<button name="cmdAvancar" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

---

No Button(asp:button) você pode usar a propriedade `OnClientClick` para programar o `onclick` (JavaScript). Também você tem o evento `OnClick` para que quando clicado seja executado um evento do Code-Behind.